# Show FPDF File in Browser does not work

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Hi people when i use this code it saves the pdf file without problem. But when i use: $pdf->Output("pdf_test.pdf", "I");. It gives me :
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

thank for helping

Comment: What code are you referring to the first time?

Comment: $pdf->Output("pdf_test.pdf", "F");   this saves the file perfectly

Comment: please provide your full code so the others can clearly pointed your problem. Do you want the to save the file and show the file on browser at the same time?